# Sync between many application servers

Tags: git, synchronization

We have an application, the main functionality of which is located in the files. Also we have GIT repo with master and production branches.

The application is located at 6 production servers with load balancing server in front.
The main problem is in synchronizing files.

At this moment we have network share with files and all servers look at it. This solution has problems with network load (at one moment there is more than 1000 connetctions to read files from share) and so it is very slow.

I have several solutions:

1. use some sync software
2. use git hooks to fetch updates from local repos and pull them on server
3. find some solution with network load

What would be optimal? and is there any other solutions?

Comment: Is there static as well as dynamic content on the servers? User images for example?

Comment: No static, only script files with integrated programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using some kind of [Continuous Integration Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)?
I don't know the details of your application, but usually CI server can automate the tests and deploy on application servers.

Depending on the language you use there are some CI servers.In my experience,for JAVA projects, [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) is a good solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with continuous integration, can you recommend any particular software? the only condition - windows platform

Comment: It depends on the platform / language you use. Anyway I've improved my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) is designed for this sort of code deployment. It updates a local copy of the site from version control into a new directory (with Git, by first updating a local repo copy, so it's very fast), and when all servers are ready with the new codebase, flips a symlink and optionally restarts the web-service so that the new version of the site is being served. If any machine fails in that task, it will roll-back all machines.

Although it was first used with a ruby on rails website, it's also been used for other languages. I've used it frequently, and very successfully, with PHP-based sites across several servers.

Comment: Well, this application (or tool) is nice, but my app is not web (php, ruby or anything else) - its complex windows application with macro-files that are edited by programmers. Your solution is good, but i need a programm to work with windows (or via RDP).